# Not able to create temp file in C Drive in windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix, sed, cygwin

I have created a shell script that does the small following task in windows:

1. Find and replace the specific content of the 'hosts' file located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" location in windows machine.

I had used cygwin application to run the shell script. My script uses 'sed' unix tool/command to find and replace the string in hosts file.

But i am getting the error saying that its unable to create the temporary file in that location. I believe the reason is because external application cannot create the file(or temp file) in that location. But 'sed' internally has to create the temporary file to achieve the find and replace task.

Please let me know how to achieve this task

Comment: Show us your script? What version of Windows are you using? Have you tried running cygwin as an administrator?

Comment: Oh!! i cant believe i missed out on running cygwin as an administrator. its working now. Thanks Josh.